# ChartJS customize left and bottom axe border

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have a chart which needs a dashed border on the left and bottom axe and a single line border on top like in the screenshot below.

[image]

This is what I achieved so far:
I used chartAreaBorder plugin to get the following example. My code for this:

```
 const chartAreaBorder = {
        id: 'chartAreaBorder',
        beforeDraw(chart, args, options) {
            const { ctx, chartArea: { left, top, width, height } } = chart
            ctx.save()
            ctx.strokeStyle = options.borderColor
            ctx.lineWidth = options.borderWidth
            ctx.borderStyle = options.borderDash
            ctx.borderTopWidth = options.borderTopWidth
            ctx.setLineDash(options.borderDash || [])
            ctx.lineDashOffset = options.borderDashOffset
            ctx.strokeRect(left, top, width, height)
            ctx.restore()
        }
    }
    const config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: data,
        plugins: [ chartAreaBorder ],
        options: {
            plugins: {
                chartAreaBorder: {
                    borderColor: '#b1b1b1',
                    borderWidth: 10,
                    /*borderWidth: {
                        top:0,
                        right:0,
                        left:10,
                        bottom:10
                    },*/
                    borderDash: [ 1, 5 ],
                    borderDashOffset: 2,
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what i get:
[image]
So my problem here is, the border is applied on every site. I couldn't find any options to hide the top/right border or to set the top/right borderWidth to 0

Is there a way to set a different border for every site of my chart?

**EDIT:**
Here is the solution for my ChartAreaBorder with the optimized code. Thanks to @LeeLenalee :)

```
const chartAreaBorder = {
    id: 'chartAreaBorder',
    afterDraw: (chart, args, opts) => {
        const {
            chartArea: {
                top,
                left,
                width,
                height
            },
            ctx
        } = chart
        const {
            borders: {
                tLtR,
                tLbL,
                tRbR,
                bLbR
            }
        } = opts
        
        ctx.save()
        
        if ( tLtR && tLtR.borderWidth !== 0 ) {
            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.strokeStyle = tLtR.borderColor || Chart.defaults.color
            ctx.lineWidth = tLtR.borderWidth || 0
            ctx.borderStyle = tLtR.borderDash || []
            ctx.setLineDash(tLtR.borderDash || [])
            ctx.lineDashOffset = tLtR.borderDashOffset || 0
            ctx.moveTo(left, top + 0.5)
            ctx.lineTo(left + width, top)
            ctx.stroke()
        }
        
        if ( tLbL && tLbL.borderWidth !== 0 ) {
            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.strokeStyle = tLbL.borderColor || Chart.defaults.color
            ctx.lineWidth = tLbL.borderWidth || 0
            ctx.borderStyle = tLbL.borderDash || []
            ctx.setLineDash(tLbL.borderDash || [])
            ctx.lineDashOffset = tLbL.borderDashOffset || 0
            ctx.moveTo(left, top)
            ctx.lineTo(left, top + height - 5)
            ctx.stroke()
        }
        
        if ( tRbR && tRbR.borderWidth !== 0 ) {
            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.strokeStyle = tRbR.borderColor || Chart.defaults.color
            ctx.lineWidth = tRbR.borderWidth || 0
            ctx.borderStyle = tRbR.borderDash || []
            ctx.setLineDash(tLbL.borderDash || [])
            ctx.lineDashOffset = tRbR.borderDashOffset || 0
            ctx.moveTo(left + width, top)
            ctx.lineTo(left + width, top + height)
            ctx.stroke()
        }
        
        if ( bLbR && bLbR.borderWidth !== 0 ) {
            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.strokeStyle = bLbR.borderColor || Chart.defaults.color
            ctx.lineWidth = bLbR.borderWidth || 0
            ctx.borderStyle = bLbR.borderDash || []
            ctx.setLineDash(bLbR.borderDash || [])
            ctx.lineDashOffset = bLbR.borderDashOffset || 0
            ctx.moveTo(left, top + height)
            ctx.lineTo(left + width, top + height)
            ctx.stroke()
        }
        
        ctx.restore()
    }
}
plugins: {
    chartAreaBorder: {
        borders: {
            tLtR: {
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#b1b1b1'
            },
            tLbL: {
                borderDash: [ 1, 5 ],
                borderWidth: 10,
                borderColor: '#b1b1b1'
            },
            tRbR: {
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            bLbR: {
                borderDash: [ 1, 5 ],
                borderWidth: 10,
                borderColor: '#b1b1b1'
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instead of drawing a rectangle at once just draw every line seperatly:

```js
const plugin = {
  id: 'chartAreaBorder',
  afterDraw: (chart, args, opts) => {
    const {
      chartArea: {
        top,
        left,
        width,
        height
      },
      ctx
    } = chart;
    const {
      borders: {
        tLtR,
        tLbL,
        tRbR,
        bLbR
      }
    } = opts;

    ctx.save();

    if (tLtR && tLtR.borderWidth !== 0) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.strokeStyle = tLtR.borderColor || Chart.defaults.color;
      ctx.lineWidth = tLtR.borderWidth || 0;
      ctx.borderStyle = tLtR.borderDash || [];
      ctx.borderTopWidth = tLtR.borderTopWidth || 0;
      ctx.setLineDash(tLtR.borderDash || []);
      ctx.lineDashOffset = tLtR.borderDashOffset || 0;
      ctx.moveTo(left, top);
      ctx.lineTo(left + width, top)
      ctx.stroke();
    }

    if (tLbL && tLbL.borderWidth !== 0) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.strokeStyle = tLbL.borderColor || Chart.defaults.color;
      ctx.lineWidth = tLbL.borderWidth || 0;
      ctx.borderStyle = tLbL.borderDash || [];
      ctx.borderTopWidth = tLbL.borderTopWidth || 0;
      ctx.setLineDash(tLbL.borderDash || []);
      ctx.lineDashOffset = tLbL.borderDashOffset || 0;
      ctx.moveTo(left, top);
      ctx.lineTo(left, top + height)
      ctx.stroke();
    }

    if (tRbR && tRbR.borderWidth !== 0) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.strokeStyle = tRbR.borderColor || Chart.defaults.color;
      ctx.lineWidth = tRbR.borderWidth || 0;
      ctx.borderStyle = tRbR.borderDash || [];
      ctx.borderTopWidth = tRbR.borderTopWidth || 0;
      ctx.setLineDash(tLbL.borderDash || []);
      ctx.lineDashOffset = tRbR.borderDashOffset || 0;
      ctx.moveTo(left + width, top);
      ctx.lineTo(left + width, top + height)
      ctx.stroke();
    }

    if (bLbR && bLbR.borderWidth !== 0) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.strokeStyle = bLbR.borderColor || Chart.defaults.color;
      ctx.lineWidth = bLbR.borderWidth || 0;
      ctx.borderStyle = bLbR.borderDash || [];
      ctx.borderTopWidth = bLbR.borderTopWidth || 0;
      ctx.setLineDash(bLbR.borderDash || []);
      ctx.lineDashOffset = bLbR.borderDashOffset || 0;
      ctx.moveTo(left, top + height);
      ctx.lineTo(left + width, top + height)
      ctx.stroke();
    }

    ctx.restore();
  }
}

const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      chartAreaBorder: {
        borders: {
          tLtR: {
            borderWidth: 0,
          },
          tLbL: {},
          tRbR: {
            borderTopWidth: 2,
            borderColor: 'red',
            lineDashOffset: 5,
            borderDash: [2, 2]
          },
          bLbR: {
            borderDash: [2, 2]
          },
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [plugin]
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much man, i could solve my problem with this solution :)

Comment: Does this example work with chartJS 2.9.4 ?